# mundane magical items

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, treasure

I am GMing a homebrew campaign using D&D 5e.  This is a world where magic is rather accessible and most cities will have a number of people making magical items.

The problem is that I dont want it to be too easy for my players to get their hands on +2 magical swords ect.

The solution I came up with is that there are higher demands for more mundane use of magic and the enchanters can make a better living making items such as amulets of rain repulsion or self cleaning clothing.  Such items whould be in greater demand by everyday people and rebalance the economy on the value of magical weapons.

The biggest problem I'm having is coming up with items that would be of little use to a traveling group of adventures to use in flavor text and as sellable loot.

So far I have:-
amulet of rain repulsion,
self cleaning clothing and
wand of dusting (wand attracts all dust within 1ft when active)

Any help with more would be great.

Comment: This is probably better asked on a forum rather than here, since we do more Q&A stuff than open-ended discussion, and more looking at extant rules than homebrewing.

Comment: We have a [list of RPG discussion forums here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) that might help you choose a good home for this discussion.

Comment: By the way, I think this is a great question, just not suited for this platform. It's a great storytelling idea.